# linq to xml query based on multiple statements in order to serve a previous / next button

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I am a newbie to Linq and having difficulties to solve an easy proble..as I 've never done before.

The scenario is a single XML table with books..like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dbproject>
<books_dataset>
<book>
  <id>23</id>
  <isbn>075221912X</isbn>
  <title>Big Brother: The Unseen Story</title>
  <author>Jean Ritchie</author>
  <publicationYr>2000</publicationYr>
  <publisher>Pan Macmillan</publisher>
  <pages>169</pages>
  <imageBigLink>/images/P/075221912X.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg</imageBigLink>
  <priceActual>0</priceActual>
  <numberOfBids>0</numberOfBids>
  <sf>kw</sf>
  <df></df>
  <ef></ef>
  <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</description>
</book>
</books_dataset>
</dbproject>
```

I am trying to create a query which gives me the ID (next one / first one) of the next/previous book which has a "kw" string in the  node.

The IDs are not continuous and there is no index. So for instance a next button is looking for an ID as follows:

1. Next (higher) ID = Next Book
2. Which has a "kw" string in

I 've tried many solutions but just got confused :/.

I am able to jump to the next/previous node.. but to be honest I am sure it isn't the best approach to achieve the task.

I am able to list the books which has a kw string but this two requirements do not work together :/

I use this query to ask for a next ID :

```
var btnNextEval = (from databack in xmlData.Element("dbproject").Elements(QRY).Elements(QRY_sub)
                           where databack.Element(fid1).Value == trgtCounter.ToString() 
                           select     databack).Single().ElementsAfterSelf().First().Element("id").Value;

trgtCounter = Convert.ToInt16(btnNextEval);
```

I tried to use && to create multiple where but didn't work :/

Please help and show me possible solutions for this silly problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var nextId = (
    from book in xmlData.Elements("book")
    let id = (int)book.Element("id")
    where ((string)book.Element("sf")) == "kw"
        && id > currentId
    select (int)book.Element("id")
).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
```

This returns the next ID. To get the book with next ID, do the following:

```
var nextBook = (
    from book in xmlData.Elements("book")
    where (int)book.Element("id") == nextId
    select book
).First();
```

Notes:

- This assumes there is a variable `currentId` of type `int` containing the current id.
- You need the `DefaultIfEmpty` in case there are no ids greater than the current one. In that case, `Min` will return an error. Using `DefaultIfEmpty(-1)` will return a single set with `-1`.
- First will also return an error if used on an empty sequence.